# SwaggerUI in Webflux - Configure actuator endpoints with different port in Swagger

Tags: swagger, spring-webflux, springdoc

i am trying to configure actuator endpoints in swagger for my springboot reactive app using **springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui** library. This can be easily done by enabling the property `springdoc.show-actuator=true` and it works fine when i get the API endpoints + actuator endpoints in the same swagger page, something like this: [image]

The problem comes when i change the port of the actuator endpoints by changing the property `management.server.port` to another port than the api's port. Then i dont get the actuator endpoints in the same swagger page as my api endpoints, instead it's divided into two groups/definitions which i can select on the top right corner of swagger, like this: [image]
, but i would like two have both of them in the same swagger page as before.

So my questions are:

1. How can i tell swagger not to divide the api & actuator endpoints into two groups, in case if the actuator endpoints running on different port
2. After i change the port of the actuator endpoints, it's not possible to call the actuator endpoints though swagger, although they are displayed there. What i get is the `TypeError: Failed to fetch` response: [image]
   But i can still make the call though curl or web browser and become the 200 response. What is the problem here?

Here is the router function for the endpoint and how i configure swagger there:

```
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> positionRoute() {
        return route().GET("/getAllPositions", accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), this::getAllPositions, ops -> ops
            .operationId("findAll").description("Get all positions").tags(new String[]{"positions"})
            .response(responseBuilder().responseCode("200").implementationArray(Position.class))).build()

            .and(route().GET("/getPosition/{id}", accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), this::getPositiionById, ops -> ops
                .operationId("findById").description("Find all").tags(new String[]{"positions"})
                .parameter(parameterBuilder().in(ParameterIn.PATH).name("id"))
                .response(responseBuilder().responseCode("200").implementation(Position.class))).build());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the management port is different from the application port and `springdoc.use-management-port` is not defined but `springdoc.show-actuator` is set to true:

- The swagger-ui will be then accessible through the application port. For example: `\http://serverName:applicationPort/swagger-ui.html`
- A dedicated group for the actuator endpoints will be by default added.
- If no group is defined for the application, a default one will be added.

TIP: If you want to reach the actuator endpoints for this case (different port from your application), `CORS` for your actuator endpoints should be enabled.

For example:

```
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-methods=GET
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=http://localhost:8080
```